# how to clear a radiobutton list after successful data insertion?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Can anybody please help me to resolve this simple issue..How to clear the selection of a radiobuttonlist after a form submission. i need to use it in my asp.net web application. when a user clicks on the clear button i need to clear the selection of radiobutton list.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could 
- either set myrbList.SelectedIndex = -1, 
- or foreach through its .Items and set each item.Selected = false

Answer (score 2):

```
RadioButtonList1.ClearSelection();
```

Answer (score 1):

//Code Example:


foreach(ListItem li in RadioButtonList1)`

{
 
 if(li.Selected)
  
 {
 
    li.Selected = false;
 
  }

}

//or use this (This is The Best

RadioButtonList1.SelectIndex = -1

Comment: should be SelectedIndex not SelectIndex

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code insted loop through each item using foreach to clear RadioButtonList

```
RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex=-1;
```